# How do I remove Google Analytics pod from Xcode project?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, google-analytics, apple-m1

New to working with Xcode. I have Google Analytics in Pods and it is causing problems... and I don't need to use it so how can I remove it? I've tried deleting it from podfile and then running pod install again but this does not do the trick.

Comment: When integrating the analytics into Pods, you can specify whether you actually need it or not. Try unchecking that option

Comment: Will look into it. Thanks!